# Getting Unknown opcode error even though Python/TF versions for train and test are the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to create a Siamese network following this tutorial https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/11/30/siamese-networks-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/

The only thing I've modified is the number of epochs in the `config.py`. Below are the commands I ran and logs generated.

```
(tf-23) D:\Code\burgle\ml>python train_siamese_network.py
2.3.0
[]
[INFO] loading MNIST dataset...
[INFO] preparing positive and negative pairs...
[INFO] building siamese network...
2023-04-23 04:58:24.093663: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
[INFO] compiling model...
[INFO] training model...
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 78s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.4952 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_accuracy: 0.4991
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 76s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.4990
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 77s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_accuracy: 0.4816
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 75s 40ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4982 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_accuracy: 0.4845
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 75s 40ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4990 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.4978
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 76s 40ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 77s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4996 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 77s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4983 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_accuracy: 0.4997
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 77s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4976 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 77s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4983 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
[INFO] saving siamese model...
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\tracking.py:111: Model.state_updates (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as updates are applied automatically.
2023-04-23 05:11:11.403233: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\tracking.py:111: Layer.updates (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as updates are applied automatically.
[INFO] plotting training history...

(tf-23) D:\Code\burgle\ml>python test_siamese_network.py --input examples
2.3.0
[INFO] loading test dataset...
[INFO] loading siamese model...
2023-04-23 15:27:34.627626: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
XXX lineno: 43, opcode: 47
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_siamese_network.py", line 27, in <module>
    model = load_model(config.MODEL_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 187, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 120, in load
    model = tf_load.load_internal(
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 632, in load_internal
    loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 194, in __init__
    super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 130, in __init__
    self._load_all()
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 221, in _load_all
    self._finalize_objects()
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 530, in _finalize_objects
    self._reconstruct_all_models()
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 548, in _reconstruct_all_models
    self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 588, in _reconstruct_model
    created_layers) = functional_lib.reconstruct_from_config(
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1214, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1162, in process_node
    output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 925, in __call__
    return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1117, in _functional_construction_call
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 903, in call
    result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Code/burgle/ml/pyimagesearch/utils.py", line 43, in euclidean_distance
    (featsA, featsB) = vectors
SystemError: unknown opcode
```

I'm using TF 2.3 as suggested by the author of the tutorial and Python3.8. Both the scripts are run in the same environment. Below is the output of my `conda list`:

```
(tf-23) D:\Code\burgle\ml>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf-23:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                     eigen
abseil-cpp                20211102.0           hd77b12b_0
absl-py                   1.3.0            py38haa95532_0
aiohttp                   3.8.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
astor                     0.8.1            py38haa95532_0
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0
async-timeout             4.0.2            py38haa95532_0
attrs                     22.1.0           py38haa95532_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blinker                   1.4              py38haa95532_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
c-ares                    1.19.0               h2bbff1b_0
ca-certificates           2022.12.7            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
certifi                   2022.12.7          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1           py38h2bbff1b_3
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.0.4            py38haa95532_0
colorama                  0.4.6            py38haa95532_0
contourpy                 1.0.5            py38h59b6b97_0
cryptography              39.0.1           py38h21b164f_0
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
eigen                     3.4.0                h2d74725_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
frozenlist                1.3.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
gast                      0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
glib                      2.69.1               h5dc1a3c_2
google-auth               2.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
grpc-cpp                  1.48.2               hf108199_0
grpcio                    1.48.2           py38hf108199_0
gst-plugins-base          1.18.5               h9e645db_0
gstreamer                 1.18.5               hd78058f_0
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.4              py38haa95532_0
importlib-metadata        6.0.0            py38haa95532_0
importlib_resources       5.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
imutils                   0.5.4            py38haa244fe_3    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py38hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.19.4               h5b6d351_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libclang                  14.0.6          default_hb5a9fac_1
libclang13                14.0.6          default_h8e68704_1
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_0
libffi                    3.4.2                hd77b12b_6
libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2
libogg                    1.3.5                h2bbff1b_1
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libprotobuf               3.20.3               h23ce68f_0
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6c2663c_2
libvorbis                 1.3.7                he774522_0
libwebp                   1.2.4                hbc33d0d_1
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h2bbff1b_1
libxml2                   2.10.3               h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt                   1.1.37               h2bbff1b_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_0
markdown                  3.4.1            py38haa95532_0
markupsafe                2.1.1            py38h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.7.1            py38haa244fe_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.7.1            py38hf11a4ad_1
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38h277e83a_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38hf11a4ad_0
multidict                 6.0.2            py38h2bbff1b_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
numpy                     1.23.5           py38h3b20f71_0
numpy-base                1.23.5           py38h4da318b_0
oauthlib                  3.2.2            py38haa95532_0
opencv                    4.6.0            py38h104de81_2
openssl                   1.1.1t               h2bbff1b_0
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
packaging                 23.0             py38haa95532_0
pcre                      8.45                 hd77b12b_0
pillow                    9.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.0.1           py38haa95532_0
ply                       3.11                     py38_0
pooch                     1.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
protobuf                  3.20.3           py38hd77b12b_0
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     2.4.0            py38haa95532_0
pyopenssl                 23.0.0           py38haa95532_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9            py38haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.7           py38hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py38hd77b12b_0
pyreadline                2.1                      py38_1
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.16               h6244533_3
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.2               he8e5bd7_8
qt-webengine              5.15.9               hb9a9bb5_5
qtwebkit                  5.212                h2bbfb41_5
re2                       2022.04.01           hd77b12b_0
requests                  2.28.1           py38haa95532_1
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1
scipy                     1.10.1           py38h321e85e_0
setuptools                66.0.0           py38haa95532_0
sip                       6.6.2            py38hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
tensorboard               2.10.0           py38haa95532_0
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1            py38haa95532_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1            py38haa95532_0
tensorflow                2.3.0           mkl_py38h8c0d9a2_0
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           eigen_py38h75a453f_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0              pyh7b7c402_0
termcolor                 2.1.0            py38haa95532_0
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.2              py38h2bbff1b_0
urllib3                   1.26.15          py38haa95532_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
werkzeug                  2.2.3            py38haa95532_0
wheel                     0.38.4           py38haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
wrapt                     1.14.1           py38h2bbff1b_0
xz                        5.2.10               h8cc25b3_1
yarl                      1.8.1            py38h2bbff1b_0
zipp                      3.11.0           py38haa95532_0
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_0
```

What seems to be the issue? All I've found regarding this error is related to issues in python versions. I've also tried using the latest TF version, however, the same error arises with additional information as seen below:

```
XXX lineno: 43, opcode: 47
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\burgle\ml\test_siamese_network.py", line 27, in <module>
    model = load_model(config.MODEL_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\heihachi\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "D:/Code/burgle/ml/pyimagesearch/utils.py", line 43, in euclidean_distance
    (featsA, featsB) = vectors
SystemError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda" (type Lambda).

unknown opcode

Call arguments received by layer "lambda" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 48), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 48), dtype=float32)']
  • mask=None
  • training=False
```

Could this github issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18660) be related?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using `tensorflow 2.4.0`. It seems it is a [known problem](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5298). There's something going on with the `Lambda` layers, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) even warns about *(de)serialization "limitations"* while using them, seems sub-classing and creating your own layer solves the problem.

What worked for me is saving the network's weights after training. Then, loading back (instantiating) the network's architecture and loading in the original weights, then predicting, like this:

```
# Creating the DNN:
def createModel():

  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

  return model


# Create the model:
model = createModel()

# Get summary:
model.summary()

# After training...

# Save the network's weights:
model.save_weights("modelWeights.h5")

# Later, possibly in another script:
model2 = createModel()

# Load the original weights:
model2.load_weights("modelWeights.h5")

# Get summary:
model2.summary()

# Predict:
predictions = model2.predict(testX)
```

In summary, save only the weights, create a new model object instantiating the network's original architecture, do not train, just load the saved weights to it, and then predict.

**Update: 09/24/2023**

I managed to solve the original issue by sub-classing the layer class, essentially writing an `EuclideanDistance` layer to compute the distance between two tensors. The implementation is straightforward, this is a new file named `EuclideanDistance.py`:

```
# Imports:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer


class EuclideanDistance(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Unpack the vectors into separate lists
        featsA, featsB = inputs
        # Compute the sum of squared distances between the vectors
        sumSquared = tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.keras.backend.square(featsA - featsB), axis=1, keepdims=True)
        # Return the euclidean distance between the vectors
        return tf.keras.backend.sqrt(tf.keras.backend.maximum(sumSquared, tf.keras.backend.epsilon()))

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        return config
```

You can instantiate the layer like this. Just pass along a list of two tensors:

```
from EuclideanDistance import EuclideanDistance
distance = EuclideanDistance()([image1Embeddings, image2Embeddings])
```

Then, to save the model you need to include a `dict` of custom objects so they can be referenced and loaded properly:

```
# Load the model. Possibly in another file:
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from EuclideanDistance import EuclideanDistance

# Include the custom objects dict:
model = load_model(modelPath, custom_objects={"EuclideanDistance": EuclideanDistance})
```