# SystemError: unknown opcode and model need compile errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `Python 3.6` and `Keras 2`. I trained and saved a model in `h5` format as follows:

```
# Encoder network
inputs_x = Input(shape=input_shape_x, name='encoder_input')
inputs_x_dropout = Dropout(0.25)(inputs_x)
inter_x1 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')(inputs_x_dropout)
inter_x2 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='tanh')(inter_x1)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(inter_x2)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(inter_x2)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = Model(inputs_x, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
 
# Decoder network for reconstruction
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
inter_y1 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='tanh')(latent_inputs)
inter_y2 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')(inter_y1)
outputs_reconstruction = Dense(original_dim)(inter_y2)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs_reconstruction, name='decoder')
 
# Separate network for prediction from latent space
outputs_prediction = Dense(Y.shape[1])(inter_y2)  # Adjust Y.shape[1] as per your data
predictor = Model(latent_inputs, outputs_prediction, name='predictor')
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC
 
# Instantiate VAE model with two outputs
outputs_vae = [decoder(encoder(inputs_x)[2]), predictor(encoder(inputs_x)[2])]
vae = Model(inputs_x, outputs_vae, name='vae_mlp')
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['mean_squared_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
 
# Train the model
history = vae.fit(X, [X, Y], epochs=5, batch_size=100, shuffle=True,validation_data=(XX,[XX, YY]), validation_split=0.0005)
 
# Save models and plot training/validation loss
encoder.save(" "+"BrmEnco Third.h5")
decoder.save(" "+"BrmDeco Third.h5")
predictor.save(" /"+"BrmPred Third.h5")
vae.save("  "+"BrmAuto Third.h5")
```

However, when I tried to load the model I always get this message

```
2024-01-14 04:26:04.136452: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
Model: "predictor"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mefgo/OneDrive - /P/CodeMatlab Simulation/Simulation.py", line 182, in <module>
    encoder = load_model("C:/Users/mefgo/OneDrive - /P/CodeMatlab Simulation/"+"BrmEnco Third.h5")
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 201, in load_model
    compile)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 181, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 52, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 212, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 678, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 663, in from_config
    config, custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1283, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1231, in process_node
    output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 977, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1115, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 848, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 888, in _infer_output_signature
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mefgo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 903, in call
    result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/mefgo/OneDrive - /PUF/CodeMatlab Simulation/Training.py", line 176, in sampling
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
SystemError: unknown opcode
```

Comment: It's due to the lambda layer, see the warning [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda). See the issue [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5298). Unless someone has another suggestion, I found these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084999/getting-unknown-opcode-error-even-though-python-tf-versions-for-train-and-test-a) possible workarounds. I had a lambda layer to calculate a distance between two tensors - ultimately, I subclassed the layer superclass and created my own layer (see third link for an example).